# SUMIFS with substrings in column

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to sum a list of values in calc.

The condition is that sum all que values in which string contains a substring stored in another column.

For example: sum all prices for healthy dishes (that contain some of the lines in D2:D4).

The formula to sum one substrings it's simply:

```
=SUMIFS(B$2:B$9;A$2:A$9;"=*"&D2&"*")
```

But how can I do to sum all the dishes with the substrings stored in D2:D4 (salad, soup, paella)?

This is a simple example.
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Edit for the below comment -filtering by month- (I'm trying using [EOMONTH](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/en-GB/text/scalc/01/func_eomonth.html) and/or [MONTHS](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060111.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3152898)):
[image]

Comment: For your example I get `SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISERROR(REGEX(LOWER(A2:A9);LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|";1;$D$2:$D$7)))));B2:B9)=77` and `=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISERROR(REGEX(LOWER(A2:A9);LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|";1;$E$2:$E$7)))));B2:B9)=100` (

Comment: I'm trying to add another column with the date (to have date-dish-price), and working on the @JohnSUN formula, I'm trying to add another element to the SUMPRODUCT, but the problem is that I'm trying to filter by month, and I can't find the way using REGEX with dates...
P.S.: I know this is a 5 month old post, but I've been trying it different ways before having to ask again